# Assigning an event function to many elements with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, action, handler

I'm building a table of links containing images with a javascript function. Here's the code:

```
    function populateGrid(dataArray) {
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        table.id = "data-table";
        var row = document.createElement("tr");

        for (var i = 1; i <= dataArray.length; i++) {
            var tableItem = document.createElement("td");
            var linkContainer = document.createElement("a");
            var itemImage = document.createElement("img");

            linkContainer.href = dataArray[i - 1].url;
            linkContainer.target = "_blank";
            itemImage.onmouseover = function(e) {
                linkHover(e);
            };
            itemImage.onmouseout = function(e) {
              linkBlur(e);
            };
            itemImage.src = dataArray[i - 1].logo;

            linkContainer.appendChild(itemImage);
            tableItem.appendChild(linkContainer);
            row.appendChild(tableItem);

            // This checks to see if it's time to make a new row, in order to keep the table a square
            if (i % Math.round(Math.sqrt(dataArray.length + 1)) === 0) {
                table.appendChild(row);
                row = document.createElement("tr");
            }
        }
        table.appendChild(row);
        document.getElementById('inject').appendChild(table);
    }
```

I'm having issues with assigning the "onmouseover" and "onmouseout" events to each individual table item. Lint is telling me that it's bad form to assign functions within a for-loop, and it definitely seems messy to me. I've tried this:

```
itemImage.onmouseover = linkHover(e);
```

But when I do it this way, I get the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined". I need some context as to which element is causing the linkHover and linkBlur functions to be called, as I change the border of the corresponding image as seen in this .gif:

(I don't have enough reputation to post images, so here's the link: http://i.imgur.com/6r8rQQp.gifv)

My linkHover and linkBlur functions are as follows:

```
    function linkHover(e) {
        e.target.className = "green-border";
    }

    function linkBlur(e) {
      e.target.className = "";
    }
```

My question is: how should I do this better? I'm sure there must be a cleaner way that doesn't give lint errors.

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT:

Okay, so following gcampbell's advice, I'm assigning the event listener to the table like so:

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.onmouseover = function(e) {
  linkHover(e);
};
table.onmouseout = function(e) {
  linkBlur(e);
};
```

And then I check to make sure the target was an img:

```
function linkHover(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == "IMG") {
    e.target.className = "green-border";
  }
}
```

Is this bad form? Should I just condense these functions into the event assignments?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) `itemImage.onmouseover = linkHover(e);` won't work because it calls the function. 2) It's better to assign the event listeners to the whole table instead of each item, as having many event listeners can impact performance.

Comment: If I assign the event listener to the table as a whole, how do I figure out which individual link was "moused-over"?

Comment: [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Comment: Edited the original post, this version works.